# Vue.js / webpack creates no build file?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This might be a stupid question but what the hell.

I am using the vue-cli `webpack-simple` template, in the webpack config of this project I find the following:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
```

No file is being built though. When running the webpack server I can access the file through the browser though. Is the `build.js` file only available when the webpack development server is running?

Is this what defines `runtime` vs `standalone`? Even after reviewing the documentation I am still confused what the exact difference is.

I need a compiled file since I am trying to publish a transpiled file to publish my package to NPM.

Cheers.

Comment: The webpack server doesn't build writing the files on the disk, it does everything in memory. So if you want to build you need to execute "npm run build".

Comment: @itacode Is it possible to create a side effect so that it also writes the files on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
npm run build
```

That will create a `/dist` directory that contains `build.js`.

You can see the scripts that are available to run in `package.json`. The `webpack-simple` template only has `run` and `build`. You'll need to copy over the `index.html` and the dist folder.

When you are developing using `npm run dev` you are using hot module reloading and no js is built a temporary one available through the hot module server.

If you want to build just one single file component you can use the `vue-cli`'s [build command](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/master/docs/build.md).

```
vue build Component.vue --prod --lib Component
```

where `Component` is the name of the single file component. This will generate a script file containing only the component you specified. Include that script in your HTML and expose it globally using `Vue.component("component", Component).

Comment: Ah I guess webpack runs everything in memory when using the vue-cli project because of the hot-reloading? I want to transpile only a single component(to start with) what would be the easiest way to do this? I just tried and the build file contains all the code needed while I just need the component that I created to be transpiled.

Comment: @Stephan-v There are two ways to easily build a single component into a script file. The `vue-cli` has a [`build`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/master/docs/build.md) command you can use. Also, the same guy that wrote the `build` part of the cli wrote a tool called [poi](https://poi.js.org/#/) that can do it as well.

Comment: Just one last question, do you have any tips for transpiling multiple components or even a Vuex module?