# Webpack create output with devserver

Tags: javascript, webpack

So according to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290965/vue-js-webpack-creates-no-build-file) webpack will not create any output when you run the devserver, it will only handle things in memory.

However if you want the devserver to also create the files and put into a certain location while running the devserver. How can you achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following plugin solved my problem: https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin